# Find distance longitude and latitude in array from user location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization, parse-platform, cllocationmanager

I have a problem when calculating the distance between my position and the coordinates obtained from an array that downloads data from a database created on Parse.com. I'd also like to find the shortest distance from my position. The code I used is this:

```
    NSString *Lat = [[object objectForKey:@"Latitudine"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString* Long = [[object objectForKey:@"Longitudine"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    Latdouble = [Lat doubleValue];
    Longdouble = [Long doubleValue];


    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Latdouble longitude:Longdouble], nil];

    NSLog(@"LOCATIONS COORDINATE: %@", locations);

    CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];;
    CLLocation *closestLocation;
    CLLocationDistance smallestDistance = DBL_MAX;

    for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
        CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location];

        NSLog(@" ");
        NSLog(@"DIST: %f", distance);
        NSLog(@" ");

        if (distance < smallestDistance) {
            distance = smallestDistance;
            closestLocation = location;

            NSLog(@"CLOSEST LOCATION: %@ \n\n DISTANCE: %f", closestLocation, distance);
        }
    }
```

I get this result when compiled:

```
2014-12-15 21:54:37.101 Veg[28614:263678] LOCATIONS COORDINATE: (
    "<+45.45592700,+11.05733500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/15/14, 10:08:08 PM Central European Standard Time"
)
2014-12-15 21:54:37.101 Veg[28614:263678] DIST: 5172045.683883
2014-12-15 21:54:37.101 Veg[28614:263678]  
2014-12-15 21:54:37.102 Veg[28614:263678] CLOSEST LOCATION: <+45.43574900,+10.98694600> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/15/14, 9:54:37 PM Central European Standard Time 

 DISTANCE: 
17976931348623157081452742373170435679807056752584499659891747680315726078002853876058955863276687817154
04589535143824642343213268894641827684675467035375169860499105765512820762454900903893289440758685084551
33942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.00
0000
```

What is wrong? Why do I get this immense value? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You're assigning in the wrong direction, you want `smallestDistance = distance` (e.g. you're logging DBL_MAX)

Comment: I just tried it, nothing to do

Comment: but DBL_MAX must be initialized with #define beginning?

Comment: You're initializing smallestDistance as DBL_MAX.  After you check that distance < smallestDistance, you're then replacing distance (which is 5172045) with smallestDistance (DBL_MAX).  What you actually want is `if (distance < smallestDistance) { smallestDistance = distance; ...`

Comment: Ok, I made the change, but what I see is the distranza in Meters, right?

Comment: That would be something to check the documentation for..  Probably!

Comment: Yes, the documentation states: "Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location."

Comment: The problem is that nell'NSLog before if the distance is 5172045.683883 (in meters from what I understand) but if I nell'NSLog inside the returns that number very long

Comment: ok guys I solved :) very kind to help. If you want to order by distance? I'm using a PFQueryTableViewController now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have:

```
if (distance < smallestDistance) {
    distance = smallestDistance;
    closestLocation = location;
```

which assigns `smallestDistance` which is initialized to `DBL_MAX` to `distance` so `smallestDistance` will never change.

What you need:

```
if (distance < smallestDistance) {
    smallestDistance = distance;
    closestLocation = location;
```

Which updates `smallestDistance` to `distance` when `distance` is smaller.